# SQL where column equals Val and equals Val2

Tags: sql

If you have a table as per bellow:

```
Col1 Col2
  1   1
  2   1
  3   1
  1   2
  3   2
  2   3
```

is there a way to write a SQL query where (Col2 =1 and Col2=2) and the result is:

```
Col1
 1
 3
```

Comment: please let me know why you down voted it, so i can ask my question better next time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this using `intersect`. Note that this wouldn't work in MySQL.

```
select col1 from tablename where col2 = 1
intersect 
select col1 from tablename where col2 = 2
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `HAVING` with `CASE WHEN`:

```
SELECT Col1
FROM your_table
GROUP BY Col1
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN Col2 = 1 THEN 1 END) > 0
   AND SUM(CASE WHEN Col2 = 2 THEN 1 END) > 0;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/400056)**</kbd>

With `MySQL` you can write:

```
SELECT Col1
FROM your_table
GROUP BY Col1
HAVING SUM(Col2 = 1) > 0
   AND SUM(Col2 = 2) > 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Self join version:

```
select distinct t1.col1
from (select col1 from tablename where col2 = 1) t1
join (select col1 from tablename where col2 = 2) t2 on t1.col1 = t2.col1
```